# warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ en utilización de INT/CHAR/FLOAT

Tags: c

Tengo este programa y sí me funciona hasta cierto punto, mi pregunta es cuál es el error que me está marcando. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
   char nombre[10];
   int edad ;
   float estatura ;
   
   printf("Cual es tu nombre?\t\n");
   scanf("%s", &nombre);
  
   printf ("Cual es tu edad?\t\n");
   scanf("%d", &edad);
   
   printf("Cuanto mides?\t\n");
   scanf("%f", &estatura);
   
   printf ("Tu nombre es %s , y tienes %d años y mides %.2f metros",nombre,edad,estatura);
   
return 0;
}
```

Supuestamente es un programa sencillo para utilizar INT/CHAR/FLOAT, pero me sale este error:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:11:12: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[10]’ [-Wformat=]
   11 |    scanf("%s", &nombre);
      |           ~^   ~~~~~~~
      |            |   |
      |            |   char (*)[10]
      |            char *
```

Estoy utilizando ONLINEGDB.COM para correrlo (en C).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es solo una advertencia. Se muestra porque el compilador se ejecuta con el parámetro `-Wformat` y los tipos no coinciden. `char *` es un puntero mientras que `char (*)[]` es puntero a un arreglo. [Puedes verlo aquí](https://tio.run/##bU85TgMxFO19iq9BgzLSZJRJGwQFDQdAoiAUHy8TS16Q/adAiENxBu6FsZ0gtilcvPU/8/XEeUpn2nEzCwkXkYT2w@GS/aSCdlPhmHYEFrVbdcBeGADwAwZw3j4GeT9uHnaFKyYpUFSgjMcMIyHNAStV3lOuJLVqrmc0WQWaTy1Xe9q7pqvGyNFlTxubHs6PchW@C@BXQzm6lBclX8Ru6b4jD1YLGZeiqkZP6//Hb79mlwVt7OEZSEtXgAB8f/MxM7Uc2mGrwEoKPn/nGOrLpv5Pe5AZONjs2GtKN94gG9l2GD@4MjjFtL5TPlikTw).

[Los arreglos decaen en punteros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Array_to_pointer_conversion), por lo tanto el operador `&` está demás. En este caso `char[]` se convierte implícitamente en `char*`. No obtienes efectos secundarios porque la dirección de la variable coincide con el primer elemento del arreglo.

Los correcto sería usar:

```
scanf("%s", nombre);
```

#### Editado

**scanf** tiene el inconveniente de que solo lee una secuencia de caracteres hasta que encuentra un espacio. Puedes obtener más información al respecto en la tabla de [esta página](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Por lo tanto, es recomendable que uses [`gets_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) (`gets` no porque no es segura), que lee hasta el salto de línea. Por ejemplo:

```
char nombre[10];
gets_s(nombre, 10);
```

O si el compilador no encuentra esa función, puedes recurrir a una muy parecida llamada [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). La diferencia sutil es que también lee el salto de línea.

Ejemplo anterior adaptado:

```
char nombre[10];
fgets(nombre, 10, stdin);

// Así puedes quitar el salto de línea 
int length = strnlen_s(nombre, 10);
nombre[length - 1] = 0;
```

Otra opción si lo prefieres, es escribir tu propia función para leer cadenas. Quizá una como esta:

```
void leer(char* buffer, int delimiter, int n){
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n - 1){
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == delimiter)
            break;

        buffer[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    buffer[i] = 0;
}
```

Puedes probarla [aquí](https://tio.run/##XZDBTsMwEETv@xWrIFSHpij0mpYv4Max5eA6m2bVZI1cBw6o3x7sxG0Re/LujN6MbFZHY8bxgcV0Q024Ofua7XP7CvBlucaOyCnTaveEh6FpyBXI4rGmjnv211XyH8Aw8c24xbKa1u@WO1KMGxRc4UsyXY0mGI/kI1zl1V1qUAVpe8/Ib1qcgyN9quB2m2vt@CPgzB/McjkvF/jvCu0uALFCr1lUqhV7oNg@8HfrMvqyLMVMnzBLBS72sihwXabKny6AGpU9nveSFQmQNEd@cDLljeObHrx2Ft@ttwC/).

Comment: Muchas gracias pero quisiera preguntar.. si en la respuesde  NOMBRE le pongo "lauro soto" como le puedo hacer para que funcione con la barra espaciadora , si nomas le pongo LAURO , fuciona pero agregando mi apellido "lauro soto" no funciona. como puedo hacer para que funcione?

Comment: @LauroSoto relacionado: [Escribir 2 valores en un 1er scanf y el 2do scanf no sea saltado en C](/questions/375367)